# Can I use IPSec for anonymous browsing (like in commercial proxies)?

Tags: proxy, ipsec

In class, we learned how to set up a VPN between two remote sites using IPSec in tunnel mode. I have a VPS for hosting my website (with root access), but if I set up a tunnel between my PC and the VPS, then my source IP will still be clear between the VPS and the internet when I browse the internet, right? (traffic is encrypted only between left and right parameters of ipsec.conf file, which are my PC and the VPS)

How do commercial proxies (such as Hotspot Shield) solve this problem?

Comment: There are a lot of layers for "Anonymous" browsing. A VPN/proxy only deals with the IP layer (and nothing else). What is your goal? What problem do you think exists?

Comment: My goal is just to understand how to hide the source IP (like all those VPSs software such as nordvpn do) because according to my understanding it is hidden in the tunnel but visible outside the tunnel (so visible between vps and target).

Comment: Then, if you ask that instead of the extra layers you've added on top, you'll get a simpler and clearer answer. The answer will depend on how you set things up to browse the internet once you have access to the VPS. You don't talk about that part. If you are setting up a proxy, then you simply need to understand how proxies work. Proxies do the browsing for you.